# How can I replace circle objects with a sphere of same radius?

Tags: custom-attributes

How to replace objects (circles) with a spheres, taking into account the radii of circles

[image]

Comment: Ctrl L > Link Object Data will replace the first selected object by the second selected object (active object), but unless the radius has been obtained with a scaling in Object mode, the replaced object won't have the good radius

Comment: Use shift+S to position the cursor on spheres, shift+A, to add spheres and set their radii to match. Then delete the circles.

Comment: does not work, scale is applied

Comment: @1so you're the one asking the question here. "does not work" doesn't help us help you, please provide additional information, a screnshot of your interface, etc.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your circles are flat on the XY plane, you could add a Geometry Nodes modifier with the following content:

[image]

Comment: does not work, scale is applied on circles

Comment: perhaps there is another option using the face area, but I can't think of it

Comment: @1so "does not work, scale is applied on circles" - well, then maybe you have to tell us a bit more about your circles or upload a file. Because this method works with and without applied scale. Unless your circle meshes are moved away from their origin in _Edit Mode_. But there is no information about that in your question.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/299994/172826
formulated the question differently

Comment: @1so it's odd that you never mentioned anything about SCALE in your post when that was integral to your primary goal. 'radius' and 'scale' are completely different terms fwiw