# How to transfer the scaling to instances?

Tags: geometry-nodes

1. There are two spheres with different scaling
2. I put them in the collection
3. I instantiate objects at the locations of the spheres from the collection

How can the scaling of the spheres be transferred to the new instances?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The node `Instance Scale` (available from version 3.3) helps you with this.

You can solve this as follows:

[image]

To do this, you must first capture the scaling of the instances in the attribute domain *Instance*, which you will use as the value for the scaling when instantiating your objects after converting them to points.